# calculating Key Check value using a Key Value

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, openssl, key-management

Iam programing in C language. I have been given TMK (Terminal master key) in componentslike for example TMK1 = 32byte hex value  TMK2 = 32 byte hex value .
I need to calculate the Key check value using these 2 Key values. 
I know DES algorithm is used in achieving this but i do not know the complete procedure. 
Please provide a sample program to do this .

Iam trying it like :

1.Take the KV: XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX YYYY YYYY YYYY YYYY

2.Divide it into a left and right part where each part is 64 bits long:
Left=XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
Right=YYYY YYYY YYYY YYYY

3.Initialize a 64-bit buffer with zeros. Call this buffer Result.

4.DES encrypt Result with Left.

5.DES decrypt Result with Right.

6.DES encrypt Result with Left

Platform : Linux , C language

Comment: Reminds me of some old ANSI banking standard, X9.9 or something like that.

Comment: You say you don't know the algorithm used, but you've told us even less about it. How could we possibly give a useful answer?

Comment: my main concern is how to divide that TMK content and use it for successive 3DES algorithm as mentioned above..

Comment: @john You have a 16-bytes triple DES key. What is the problem then? The steps you have mentioned are correct.

Comment: Assuming you use 3DES then it is as easy as:
[Calculating 3DES Key Check Value (KCV)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37379/calculating-3des-key-check-value-kcv)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you a code right now but I would suggest that you treat KV as a string (or array or characters) so that you can easily divide it into two portions. something like that.

Comment: KV is given as hexadecimal values ...do i have to convert it into ASCII and then use or should i use them as it is.

Comment: @john:  Don't convert it to ASCII.  It's binary data so use it directly.